# Creating DTD (Document Type Definition) file using atrributes, fixed, required, implied etc

Tags: xml, dtd, dtd-parsing

We only talk about DTD and XML in class for 2 days and i have this assignment not sure if im doing it right or did everything that has been asked. Atleast i try, any help will be appreciated!!

Assignment
You have been asked to represent airport data where an airport has  required attributes name and location;  and an implied attribute famous_assoiciation.  The famous_assoication attribute is the name of a famous person after whom the airport has been named.  An  airport is composed of one or more hangers.  Each hanger has a number, location and a set of 0 or more associated airlines.  Each hanger also has a fixed attribute, length, of 2 miles.   An  airline has a name, one of more  types of  aircraft fleets (where a fleet contains one or more planes).   A plane has a manufacturer, model, vin and seat_capacity.  A plane also has attribute color with a default value of “silver”

You may assume that all data in this system is of type CDATA

This is what i did...

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>

<!ELEMENT airport (hanger+)>
 <!ELEMENT hanger (number, location, airline*)>
 <!ELEMENT number (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT location (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT airline (name, aircraft fleets+)>
 <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT aircraft fleets (plane+)>
 <!ELEMENT plane (manufacturer, model, vin, seat_capacity)>
 <!ELEMENT manufacturer (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT vin (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT seat_capacity (#PCDATA)>


 <!ATTLIST airport name CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST airport location CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST airport famous_assoiciation CDATA #IMPLIED>
 <!ATTLIST plane color CDATA #FIXED "silver">
 <!ATTLIST hanger length CDATA #FIXED "2 miles">
```

Comment: The line `<!ELEMENT aircraft fleets (plane+)>` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DTD looks pretty good. I only see a few things.

---

An element can't have a space in the name, so you'll have to change `aircraft fleets`. There's no reason you couldn't shorten it to `fleet`.

---

For readability, it's good practice to put the attribute declaration (`ATTLIST`) under the element declaration so it's easy to find. You also only need one `ATTLIST` per element. You can add linebreaks and tabs/spaces to make it easy to read...

```
<!ELEMENT airport (hanger+)>
<!ATTLIST airport 
          name                CDATA #REQUIRED
          location            CDATA #REQUIRED
          famous_assoiciation CDATA #IMPLIED   >
```

---

The `color` attribute is supposed to have a default value of "silver", but you have it as a fixed value. Just remove `#FIXED`...

```
<!ATTLIST plane color CDATA "silver">
```

Comment: Appreciate it and one more question do i need <?xml version = "1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?> on top of my dtd file? or its for xml file

Comment: @sean - Good question. I wouldn't put the XML declaration inside of an external DTD. However, I'm not sure if it would really make a difference. I'm also not sure what having an XML declaration in both the DTD and the XML does. It might be worth some experimentation. Take a look at what the spec says for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: @sean - Also, if this answer was sufficient, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark next to it. Thanks!